# Selenium refresh

Tags: selenium, groovy, spock

I am working on project where everything is saved in events so it took some time for server to respond for new data. I am using Fluent wait for pages using ajax, but this one doesn't use any ajax. So I want to refresh page check if new item is there if not refresh again. How this is achieved in Selenium 2?

I did this :

```
        def accountsAfterCreating = 0
        while (accountsAfterCreating <= existingAccounts) {
            driver.navigate().refresh()
            WebElement table = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return driver.findElement(By.className("table"))
                }
            })
            accountsAfterCreating = table.findElements(By.className("amount")).size()
        }
```

Is it correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with answer like this. This will work only on groovy because it is using closure

```
    private boolean refreshUntil(Closure<Boolean> condition) {
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException)
    wait.until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
        boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            driver.navigate().refresh()
            if (condition()) {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    })
    return true
}
```

and calling this method

```
refreshUntil {
            accountsBeforeCreation + 1 == driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"))).size()
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Explicit wait like this In try catch block

try{

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

}

```
catch()
```

{

```
driver.navigate().refresh()
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this method to wait for any html tag. We can also specify the wait time.

```
public boolean waitForElement(WebElement ele, String xpath, int seconds) throws InterruptedException{
    //returns true if the element appears within the time
    //false when timed out
    int t=0;
    while(t<seconds*10){
        if(ele.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).size()>0)
            return true;
        else{
            Thread.sleep(100);
            t++;
            continue;
        }
    }       
    System.out.println("waited for "+seconds+"seconds. But couldn't find "+xpath+ " in the element specified");
    return false;
}
```